# Mapping Out(F_n) to the mapping class group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-groups

Let $\mathrm{Out}(F_g)$ denote the automorphism group of a free group, and $\mathrm{Mod}_g$ the mapping class group of a closed oriented genus $g$ surface. Is there a map, as indicated with the dashed arrow below, making the following diagram commute?

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
    \mathrm{Out}(F_g) & \dashrightarrow & \mathrm{Mod}_g \\
    \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
    \mathrm{GL}(g,\mathbf Z) & \to & \mathrm{Sp}(2g,\mathbf Z) \\
\end{array}
$$
The lower horizontal map is induced by the functor $V \mapsto V \oplus V^\ast$ taking a vector space of dimension $g$ to a $2g$-dimensional symplectic vector space.

I do have a reason for asking but it's too long of a story to write here.

Comment: Don't we even expect that $\mathrm{Out}(F_4)$ doesn't embed into any mapping class group? More precisely, if we consider the HNN-extension of $F_2\times F_2$ by the partial isomorphism $(x,x)\mapsto (x,1)$, does it embed into any MCG? If I remember correctly, it embeds into $\mathrm{Out}(F_4)$ and this is used to prove the nonlinearity of the latter.

Comment: @YCor That's a nice comment, thanks. So we shouldn't expect to have a "cheap" construction of an injection from $\mathrm{Out}(F_g)$ to $\mathrm{Mod}_g$, since for $g\geq 4$ it would resolve a big open problem. On the other hand I did not require the map to be injective.

Comment: If you have any homomorphism with infinite image, you get an infinite subgroup of MCG with Property T, and this is unknown too.

Comment: Very curious about the long story if you can say a bit!

Comment: Just a thought on how one might try to rule this out—such a diagram would induce a map on relative completions, in the sense of Hain. I don’t know if anyone has worked out the lower central series of the unipotent radical of the relative completion of Out(F_n), but the Mod_g side is relatively well-understood, by Hain…

Comment: @DanielLitt has a tropical feel to it

Comment: @DanielLitt: Trying to do for Out(F_n) what Hain did for the mapping class group is a notorious open question.  It is not even known whether or not the associated Lie algebra for Out(F_n) is finitely presented.

Comment: @AndyPutman: Good to know! I've been thinking a bit about Aut(F_n) and Out(F_n) recently, maybe will see if I can get anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out by YCor, $\mathrm{Out}(F_g)$ is not linear (for $g \geq 3$).  Also, the linearity of $\mathrm{Mod}(S_g)$ is unknown.  So the existence of such an embedding would solve a long-standing open question.  I suspect that there is no such embedding.

However, perhaps you would be interested in a substitute.  Let $V_g$ be the three-dimensional handlebody of genus $g$.   Note that $\partial V_g = S_g$.  Let $\mathrm{Mod}(V_g)$ be the resulting mapping class group.  Restricting to the boundary gives a monomorphism $r \colon \mathrm{Mod}(V_g) \to \mathrm{Mod}(S_g)$.  On the other hand, mapping classes act (via outer automorphism) on the space's fundamental group.  So we have a epimorphism (as it turns out) $f \colon \mathrm{Mod}(V_g) \to \mathrm{Out}(\pi_1(V_g)) \cong \mathrm{Out}(F_g)$.  Thus instead of a commuting square there is a pentagon.

Comment: The restriction map $Mod(V_g) \rightarrow Mod(S_g)$ is not surjective (but it is injective).

Comment: Whoops, absolutely. Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks. The map from Mod(V_g) is what I should have been thinking about all along.

Comment: Sebastian Hensel has claimed that there is no section from $Out{F_g)$ to $Mod(V_g)$, but it appears that the paper was taken down. See reference 22 in this paper: https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~hensel/papers/hno4.pdf

Answer (score 4):

This works for $g=2$, but it’s a very special case. $Out(F_2)\cong GL_2(
\mathbb{Z}) \cong Mod_1 \cong Mod_{1,1}$, the mapping class group of a pointed torus. This is realized by the linear action of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on $T^2=\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ fixing the origin. Taking the oriented blowup of the action at the origin (blowup by rays), one obtains an action of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on the surface $\Sigma_{1,1}$, a genus 1 surface with one boundary component. Then $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on $\Sigma_{1,1}\times [-1,1]$, which is homeomorphic to a genus 2 handlebody and boundary homeomorphic to the double of $\Sigma_{1,1}$ along its boundary, ie $\Sigma_2$ the closed connected orientable surface of genus 2. The first homology splits as a direct sum into $H_1(\Sigma_{1,1} \times \{1\})$ and $H_1(\Sigma_{1,1}\times \{-1\})$, in such a way that the action of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts by the dual action on the second factor since the identification by the product with $[-1,1]$ reverses orientation. Hence this gives the sort of homomorphism you seek in this case.